# Google Cloud Firestore: How to list document with subcollections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to get document ids from this database structure.
In other words, I'd like to get list(2019, 2020...) from following database.

[scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUVAM.png)

I use javascript. (web client)
And following code does not work well.
`querySnapshot.docs` is empty array.

```js
getYears() {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const query = db.collection(`users/${currentUser.uid}/statics`);
  query.get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      console.log('querySnapshot', querySnapshot);
      querySnapshot.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
        console.log('docSnapshot id', docSnapshot.id);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err', err);
    });
```

Comment: In what programming language? Besides that, instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I added a screenshot and my code.

Comment: I've tried your code and it worked fine. Then tried it with `currentUser.uid` not present in users and got the same result as you. I would say log your `currentUser.uid` and check if you have document with such id in your collection.

Comment: @EmilGi  
Thank you for trying at your environment. I've confirmed logs again but logs show `currentUser.uid` is valid user.    
As a test, when I specified the full path `const query` such a `users/${currentUser.uid}/statics/2020/gymCounter`, I could get doc ids.

Comment: No idea what can cause this then, check if you get the same result with other collections, try updating library, unlikely but maybe there are some encoding issues. If nothing helps and you have [support package](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs)  open a ticket with GCP support. Also I am assuming this line `console.log('querySnapshot', querySnapshot);` already doesn;t output any documents?

Comment: I'm sorry for responding too late.
I tried updating firebase library, but it doesn't work.
In this line `console.log('querySnapshot', querySnapshot);`, There is no document such as `{ docs: Array(0), empty: true, size: '0 }`.